# Based on the mat tab click Mat expand collapse should display

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, angular8, mat-tab

I am working currently Mat tabs (vertical) in one component & Mat expand collapse in other component based on the click of mat tab the relevant Mat expand should display.

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-and-expand-collpse) which I am working on.

Comment: You stackblitz is not loading for me.

Comment: @MattNienow the same link is working for me

Comment: @Mahadevan Link is not working

Comment: @Allabakash can you please check now

Comment: @MattNienow please check I have updated with correct link

Comment: @Mahadevan link is working, what is the expectation ?

Comment: Without code in the question, this post lacks a [mcve] and is thus not on-topic. Please always add code to the question itself, and add external runner links at the end as an optional addendum.

Answer (score -1):

Use import like this

```
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
```